# How to undo a copy command

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> a lot!

The issue is, on a keyboard, the <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> are beside each other. I often hit the wrong thing and end up copying new text instead of pasting what is in the clipboard.

Since I'm copying and pasting within remote desktop as well, it's a little time consuming to go back and re-copy the original text when I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Is there a way to "undo" the last copy and as such return to the previous "item" in the clipboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With stock Windows there is not a way to accomplish this. What you would need to use to accomplish this would be a [clipboard manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager). There are a lot of them out there.